# Repeater div id changing inside repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to change the id of certain div/divs inside of repeater is there any psefic way to do it and can you be please explain basicaly.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <li id="11">
        <img src="../<%#Eval("MediumPath")%>"class="items"alt='<%#Eval("Alt") %>'>
        <br clear="all" />
        <div><%# Eval("ProductName")%></div>
     </li>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Change it how, code-behind or javascript? Or modify the HTML to just use a Eval? and what do you mean by certain divs, what logic determines which ones should change?

Comment: Since you're binding data from db, Why don't you use any unique id concatenated with static text like `<li id="'prod_' + <%# Eval("ProductID") %>'"`

Comment: it is actually counting number lets say 1 to 16  i want  need to know every "li =id" so how can i change this id because its inside repeater and how should i use  Eval  if its the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use container.ItemIndex, which gets the item index from the repeater. Just a note that it's 0 indexed so the actual code will be:

```
<li id="<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>">
```